# Is there a usable implementation of PBFT?

Tags: fault-tolerance, byzantine

In the [original Practical Byzantine Fault Tolerance (PBFT) paper](http://pmg.csail.mit.edu/papers/osdi99.pdf) they mention they implemented a fault tolerant NFS service. To do that they made a library for PBFT. Does that exist anywhere?

As that paper is quite old now and was well received, I thought it should not be hard to find implementations. However so far I only found incomplete and abandoned experiments.

[RAFT has a list of implementations on their website](https://raft.github.io/#implementations). I am looking for something like this in the byzantine case.

Comment: Questions about software libraries are generally off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily NFS, but Hyperledger used PBFT for their blockchain platform.

This is a Go implementation: https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/tree/master/consensus/pbft

That is an old repo, they seem to be currently using a new repo with implementations in other languages as well, however I haven't gone through it in detail:
https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/admin/projects/

There are more related details in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710738/pbft-algorithm-in-hyperledger

Good luck

Comment: This looks like a reasonable answer but note that questions seeking code, programs, libraries, etc. are [off-topic here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).